CORS Preflight Failing for SignalR Connection in ASP.NET Core with HttpOnly Cookie Authentication
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application with a Vue.js frontend, and I'm trying to implement SignalR for real-time notifications. However, I'm encountering a CORS issue when attempting to connect to my SignalR hub. Below are the details of my setup and the errors I'm facing.
Project Setup

Frontend: Vue.js, configured with withCredentials: true to send cookies.
Backend: ASP.NET Core with JWT authentication, using HttpOnly cookies to store JWTs.

CORS Configuration
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                string[] origins = [.. SecretsManager.GetSecret("Cors:AllowedOrigins").Split(',')];

                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigins",
                    b => b.WithOrigins(origins)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                );
            });

JWT Configuration
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = SecretsManager.GetSecret("Jwt:Issuer"),
                    ValidAudience = SecretsManager.GetSecret("Jwt:Audience"),
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecretsManager.GetSecret("Jwt:Key"))
                    )
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
                    {
                        ctx.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("access_token", out var accessToken);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                        {
                            ctx.Token = accessToken;
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization();

SignalR Setup in Vue.js
    onMounted(() => {
    connection.value = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://localhost:5132/api/NotificationHub', {
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .build();

    connection.value.start()
        .then(() => console.log('SignalR Connected'))
        .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));

NotificationHub.cs
    [HubEndpoint("api/NotificationHub")]
    [Authorize]
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("CreateMovie", user, message);
        }
    }

Error Details
    Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5132/api/NotificationHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
The preflight OPTIONS request returns a 401 Unauthorized response with a WWW-Authenticate: Bearer header.

If I remove Authorize attribute everything works fine and connection is established
but when I have [Authorize] Attribute on Hub class it fails the authorization.
but even it fails I can still access the userID for example in OnConnectedAsync of NotificationHub class.
I cannot pass the cookie from client side as well as it is httponly.
can anyone help me find the solution to use Authorize attribute on Hubs? and establish connection only if user is authorized?
thanks

It's not cors issue. If it's cors issue, when we remove the [Authorize]  attribute, we can still see the cors error  message.

the only stupidest problem was that I had written UseCors() after UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() methods and after I changed the order like this in config files everything was fixed. I almost waste 2 days for this problem. which was of course my fault.
    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins");

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();


You should use accessTokenFactory instead of withCredentials: true.
Official Doc: Configure bearer authentication

I cannot get the token from cookies using js as it is hhtponly cookie, and the cookie is set from backend on same subdomain

@b.tsutskiridze Maybe we can create a custom api to get the token, code snippet like  https://i.sstatic.net/cObQ1GgY.png

Thanks for the suggestion. If I do that it will Expose the JWT token to the frontend and can reintroduce vulnerabilities, particularly XSS and the reason I tried to use http only cookies for auth was mainly to prevent that.

@b.tsutskiridze If you can follow my suggestion to verify it, then you can create a new post with   the security way to  use http only cookies for auth topic. It will attract more people's attention.
